# How to fetch all rows and columns from grid view dynamically in data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written below lines of code

```
       DataTable dataTable = grdServiceList.DataSource as DataTable;

        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

            grdServiceList.DataSource = dataView;
            grdServiceList.DataBind();
        }
         public void bind()
        {
         IEnumerable<_14Muslims.Domain.Entity.Service> Services = context.ServicesFetchWithPaging(ctlPager.PageIndex, ctlPager.PageSize, SearchHint, CountryID, Street, State, City);//.OrderBy(DataGridSortBy);
        grdServiceList.DataSource = Services;
        grdServiceList.DataBind();
        }
```

After checking in debuger mode datatable contains null values

Comment: Datatable is null or datatables has null values in columns ?

Comment: On which event do you want to get datatable ? i.e page_load, some button click ?

Comment: What is datasource of gridview ?

Comment: have updated my question

Comment: You need to cast it in `IEnumerable<_14Muslims.Domain.Entity.Service>` object.

Answer (score 0):

You said `datatable contains null`; with that I believe your `grdServiceList.DataSource` is not of `DataTable` type and so the casting with `as` returning `NULL`. I mean the below line

```
DataTable dataTable = grdServiceList.DataSource as DataTable;
```

I am pretty much sure, if you do a explicit cast instead of using `as` like `DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)grdServiceList.DataSource;`  it would throw a `InvalidCastException`.

Just a guess but try casting it to `DataSet` and see if works

```
   DataSet ds = grdServiceList.DataSource as DataSet;

    if (ds != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

        grdServiceList.DataSource = dataView;
        grdServiceList.DataBind();
    }
```